# Symfony 4 Embed Forms - Embed Part Only

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, embed

I have 2 entities: Article, Comment

Each have their own FormType -> ArticleType, CommentType

---

To create Articles, I just use the ArticleType to create a Form.

For the Comments I use my CommentType, but I also want to modify some information from the Article.

For example: Add Comment and be able to change Article categories.

This means I need to add the Article-Category field to my CommentType. Since there are ways to embed to complete form. I was wondering if I can only embed part of the form.

ArticleType:

```
$builder->add('headline', TextType::class, [ ... ])
        ->add('text', TextType::class, [ ... ])
        ->add('category', EntityType:class, [ ... ])
```

CommentType:

```
$builder->add('article', ArticleType::class, [ ... ])
//adds all fields of ArticleType, but only want the category field
```

Is there any way too approach this, without having to add the category part from my ArticleType? (prevent duplication of code).

Also I was wondering how the controller would look like for my case.
Right now I use following code, which might need improvments:

```
/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}", name="app_article")
 */
public function article(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setArticle($article); //to modify current article values

    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tmpArticle = $comment->getArticle(); //if I don't get the article from my comment, doctrine/symfony creates a *new* Article - which I dont want
        $article->setCategory($tmpArticle->getCategory());

        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
    }

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I changed my ArticleType to use all fields default, but when I use specific option it just uses the few fields I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want choose an existing Article for Category. 
Should you use EntityType : [Link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

With parameters you can choose label in select.

Comment: That's what I do right now. Sadly I do not like this solution, because I also use FormEvents to change the form dynamically.

If I use EntityType, I need to rewrite all of the FormEvents, which I pratically already have.

Example: If I choose a category, I get a select with sub-categories.

That's the reason I want to use my ArticleType, so I do (if possible) not need to duplicate everything :)

Comment: Maybe my idea is dumb.. If you write : $builder->add('article.category', EntityType:class, [ ... ])

Comment: dots [.] are illegal characters in this context =)
Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").